# What is the different between filter and filter-map?

Tags: racket

I'm trying to understand what [count](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._count%29%29) do.

I have read the documentation, and it says:

> Returns (length (filter-map proc lst ...)), but without building the
>   intermediate list.

Then, I have read [filter-map](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._filter-map%29%29) documentation, and it says:

> Returns (filter (lambda (x) x) (map proc lst ...)), but without
>   building the intermediate list.

Then, I have read [filter](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._filter%29%29) documentation, and I have understand it.

But, I don't understand [filter-map](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._filter-map%29%29). In particular that`(lambda (x) x)` in `(filter (lambda (x) x) (map proc lst ...))`.

What is the different between `filter` and `filter-map`?

By the way, the examples of `filter` and `filter-map` do the same and that make it more difficult to understand them.

Comment: `(filter-map (lambda (x) (if (even? x) (list x x) #f)) '(1 2 3 4 5))` ==> `'((2 2) (4 4))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point is that if you know `filter` and `map` well, then you can explain `filter-map` like that. If you do not know what `filter` and `map` does it will not help you understand it. When you need to learn something new you often need to use prior experience. Eg. I can explain multiplication by saying `3 * 4` is the same as `3 + 3 + 3 + 3`, but it doesn't help if you don't know what `+` is.

What is the difference between `filter` and `filter-map`

```scm
(filter odd? '(1 2 3 4 5))     ; ==> (1 3 5)
(filter-map odd? '(1 2 3 4 5)) ; ==> (#t #t #t))
```

The first collects the original values from the list when the predicate became truthy. In this case `(odd? 1)` is true and thus `1` is an element in the result.

`filter-map` doesn't filter on `odd?` it works as if you passed `odd?` to `map`. There you get a new list with the results.

```scm
(map odd? '(1 2 3 4 5))                   ; ==> (#t #f #t #f #t #f)
```

Then it removes the false values so that you only have true values left:

```scm
(filter identity (map odd? '(1 2 3 4 5))) ; ==> (#t #t #t)
```

Now. It's important to understand that in Scheme every value except `#f` is true. 
`(lambda (x) x)` is the identity function and is the same as `identity` in `#lang racket`. It returns its own argument.

```scm
(filter identity '(1 #f 2 #f 3)) ; ==> (1 2 3)
```

`count` works the same way as `filter-map` except it only returns how many element you would have got. Thus:

```scm
(count odd? '(1 2 3 4 5)) ; ==> 3
```

Now it mentions that it is the same as:

```scm
(length (filter identity (map odd? '(1 2 3 4 5)))
```

Execpt for the fact that the the code using `map`, `filter`, and `length` like that creates 2 lists. Thus while count does the same it does it without using `map` and `filter`. Now it seems this is a primitive, but you could do it like this:

```scm
(define (count fn lst)
  (let loop ((lst lst) (cnt 0))
    (cond ((null? lst) cnt)
          ((fn (car lst)) (loop (cdr lst) (add1 cnt)))
          (else (loop (cdr lst) cnt))))
```

Answer (score 4):

I would say that the key insight here is that in the context of `filter`, you should read `(lambda (x) x)` as `not-false?`. So, the documentation for filter-map could be written to read:

Returns `(filter not-false? (map proc lst ...))`, but without building the intermediate list, where `not-false?` can be defined as `(lambda (x) x)`.

Comment: followup: a doc change has now been proposed to clarify this. Thanks to @VansFannel for the prompt!

Comment: You are welcome. I'm glad to be part of the community.